# mysql query timestamp = datestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that looks at the timestamp to match , but the two time stamps have difference mins and sec . how to make the query just look at the date /hour/ and min ?

My Query

```
 select 
  t1.*,
  t2.* 
 from  
db1 t1 ,db2 t2 where t1.table like 'id' 
and  date(t1.DATE)=date(t2.DATE)
```

The timestamp

```
2016-03-20 00:08:02 2016-03-20 00:08:15
```

Comment: If the mins are different, why look at them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need Hour only

```
select 
      t1.*,
      t2.* 
     from  
    db1.t1 ,db2.t2 where t1.table like '%id%' 
    and  DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, '%Y-%m-%d %H')=DATE_FORMAT(t2.date, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

if you need hour+minute then

```
select 
  t1.*,
  t2.* 
 from  
db1.t1 ,db2.t2 where t1.table like '%id%' 
and  DATE_FORMAT(t1.date, '%Y-%m-%d %H %i')=DATE_FORMAT(t2.date, '%Y-%m-%d %H %i')
```